# how to format my text dataset for training?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, training-data, file-format

I'm new to python and machine learning, 
I'm working on training a chatbot

I collected (or wrote) large number of possible inputs in an excel file (.xlsx), I will train my dataset using LSTM and IOBES lableing, I will do the same as here :
https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/guide-sequence-tagging-neural-networks-python/

In the link you can see a snapshot of the dataset, I want to make my dataset like it.

my questions are :

1- Is there a way to split a sentence into words so I can do the tagging for words ? (there is a tool in Excel, I tried it but it is very exhausted).
2- I tried to convert my file to .cvs, but I've faced a lot of problems (it is with utf-8, because my dataset is not in english) , is there another extension ?

I really appreciate your help and advice.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pandas` method `pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx',sep=',')` to avoid converting your file into csv.

To split a sentence into words you need to use a Natural Language Processing (NLP) python package like `nltk` with an English vocabulary. This will take into account punctuation, quotes etc..

Answer (score 0):

I'm using openpyxl to load excel file directly into memory. For instance,

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
trainingFile = './InputForTraining/1.labelled.Data.V2.xlsx'
trainingSheet = 'sheet1'
TrainingFile = load_workbook(trainingFile)
sheet = TrainingFile[trainingSheet]
```

Then you don't have to convert excel to csv. Sometime if the data structure is every complicated, the converting is not that simple. You still have to write some code to form the structure.
For split sentence is quite easy if your sentence is quite clean. Python has function split() to split your string to a list of words based on space. For instance,

```
wordsList = yourString.split()
```

But you will need to be careful about punctuation. It usually follows right after a word. You can use regEx to split punctuation to a word. For instance,

```
pat = re.compile(r"([.,;:()/&])")
return_text = pat.sub(" \\1 ", return_text)
wordList = return_text.split()
```

So [.,;:()/&] will be split from a word. 
Or maybe you can even just remove punctuation from sentences if you don't need them at all. And replace them as space. For instance,

```
return_text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z\s1234567890]+", ' ', text).strip().rstrip()
```

Then only letters and numbers will be remained.
.strip().rstrip() is removing extra spaces.